# Explicitly specializing a deleted primary template

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-specialization

GCC accepts this but Clang rejects it as a redefinition:

```
template< typename >
void s() = delete;

template<>
void s< int >() {}
```

Who is right?

Answer (score 4):

It is a [Clang bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17537)  and also [CWG DR 941](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#941), which was already adopted by C++11. Clang is nonconforming.